# Stored procedure running very badly when a COMPUTED field is referenced

Tags: sql-server

The SQL query runs in SSMS in about 1.4 seconds and as a stored procedure in 45 seconds.

I initially thought of the dreaded 'parameter sniffing' but I did my usual 'trick' of assigning the passed parameters to local parameters within the stored procedure (that usually fixes it). However, the stored procedure still runs like a dog.

There are some slight differences in the execution plan.

SSMS:
[image]

Stored procedure:
[image]

The SQL is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_test]
    (
        @Latitude Float = 51,
        @Longitude Float = 0,
        @DistanceMax INT = 125
    )

    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

    DECLARE 
        @LocalLatitude FLOAT = @Latitude,
        @LocalLongitude FLOAT = @Longitude,
        @LocalDistanceMax INT = @DistanceMax

    CREATE TABLE #PostcodeSubset
    (
        PostcodeSubsetId INT NOT NULL identity(1,1),
        District VARCHAR(8),
        DistrictSort1 VARCHAR(4),
        DistrictSort2 INT,
        DistrictLatitude FLOAT,
        DistrictLongitude FLOAT,
        UNIQUE CLUSTERED (PostcodeSubsetId)
    )

    INSERT INTO
        #PostcodeSubset
            (
                District,
                DistrictSort1,
                DistrictSort2,
                DistrictLatitude,
                DistrictLongitude
            )
    SELECT DISTINCT
        District AS District,
        DistrictSort1 AS DistrictSort1,
        DistrictSort2 AS DistrictSort2,
        DistrictLatitude AS DistrictLatitude,
        DistrictLongitude AS DistrictLongitude
    FROM
        PostcodeData
    WHERE
        (
            ACOS
            (
                COS(RADIANS(90-@LocalLatitude))
                *COS(RADIANS(90-DistrictLatitude))
                +SIN(RADIANS(90-@LocalLatitude)) 
                *SIN(RADIANS(90-DistrictLatitude))
                *COS(RADIANS(@LocalLongitude-DistrictLongitude))
                )
            *3959 <= @LocalDistanceMax
        ) 

    SELECT
        (
            SELECT
                PCS.District,
                PCS.DistrictLatitude,
                PCS.DistrictLongitude,
                PD.Sector
            FROM
                #PostcodeSubset PCS
            INNER JOIN 
                PostcodeData PD ON PCS.District = PD.District
            GROUP BY 
                PCS.District,
                PCS.DistrictSort1,
                PCS.DistrictSort2,
                PCS.DistrictLatitude,
                PCS.DistrictLongitude
,               PD.Sector
            ORDER BY 
                PCS.DistrictSort1,
                PCS.DistrictSort2,
                PD.Sector
            FOR JSON AUTO
        ) AS JSONData 

    DROP TABLE 
        #PostcodeSubset
```

The real performance breakthrough came when I removed a `COMPUTED` columns `DistrictSort1` and `DistrictSort2` from the query and it now ran as a stored procedure at around the same speed as is does in SSMS and the execution plan is in line with the SSMS one.

I checked the `COMPUTED` columns and 'Is Persistent' is set to true on both.

Is there any known issue with `COMPUTED` columns causing performance issues with stored procedures and if so what are the workarounds?

Comment: Hard to say without 1) your *actual* query in your *actual* stored procedure (rather than the truncated stuff we got) and 2) execution plans that can be read in full (use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). No, there are no general "don't use computed columns in stored procedures" tips or suchlike, but I can think of a few things that can influence plan generation. Those are not necessarily directly related to the computed column, though, if it's simply a result of the column getting computed at all or not.

Comment: `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` looks like a potential problem -- this prevents indexes on computed columns from working. Note that in the plan you pasted for the stored procedure, `ANSI_WARNINGS` is `ON` and indeed the plan does not resemble the one in the screenshot. Also (though I don't think this will change things much) instead of doing the "assign to local variables" trick to circumvent parameter sniffing, try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the `INSERT` query. If rather the values you've specified for defaults are reasonable, try `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ...)`.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ5-Uh5D5 doesn't even mention `DistrictSort1` or `DistrictSort2`

Comment: Looks like it's a parameter type issue: you have `int` as the data type for `@DistanceMax` but it should be `float` to match the comparison you are doing. Also unclear why you need a temp table here: why not just use derived tables or CTEs. Equally unclear why you need a join at all, given that they are coming from the same table

Comment: You are right the parameter type was wrong and has been corrected - appreciate the heads-up (edited accordingly). This does not, however affect the speed of the query. '''SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF''' is the problem and setting this to ```ON``` is the solution.
Waiting for the solution to be added by Jeroen.

Comment: The table join is not needed, however, as part of the investigation I was splitting the query down to narrow down the area causing the issue. This was a working 'test set' and as such should not be 'marked' as a finished solution.

Answer (score 0):

As identified in the comments; setting `ANSI_WARNINGS` is `ON` results in the `COMPUTED` field not being used for indexing. This in turn causes the performance degradation in the stored procedure over the non SP version (running in SSMS).